# How long does it take for the potted plants to grow?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

There are some Power Moons that you can only get by planting seeds in pots. Once the seed is planted, it takes some time to grow before you can harvest the power moon from it.

How long does it take?

Comment: The first ones I've seen are in the Sand Kingdom, but I've also seen them in Seaside Kingdom and the Metro Kingdom.

Comment: In multiple for sure, but I don't think it's in all. There are a few worlds where I haven't encountered seeds or pots.

Comment: I planted a flower when I first reached the Sand Kingdom. After clearing the boss there, I noticed that it was fully grown.

Comment: The growth is definitely time based. I planted a seed in the Lake Kingdom and let my Switch idle for about an hour. When I came back, the plant was fully grown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It varies depending on the plant’s size. 3 leaves grow every 3 minutes, while the bulb takes 9 minutes to grow.

Based on my experiments in the Sand Kingdom, I initially assumed that each plant took 21 minutes to grow to full size. However, I have since learned that the time it takes will vary depending on the size of the plant.

**On average each plant should take around 15-24 minutes to grow, but it can vary.**

A few notes:

- The largest plant was in Seaside Hill. It had 45 leaves and took 54 minutes to grow
- You can make the plants in Seaside Hill grow faster by capturing a squid and watering them. ([Thanks raznagul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320501/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-potted-plants-to-grow#comment464670_320825))

---

**Old answer**

Based on [Nolonar's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320501/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-potted-plants-to-grow#comment456210_320501), I knew that the plant would grow if I left my Switch idle. So I went to the Sand Kingdom, set a timer on my phone, and waited.

**0 - 12 minutes**

For the first twelve minutes the plant gained three new leaves every three minutes. This means you could use leaves to tell how long the plant had been growing. (**3 leaves = 3 minutes**)

**12- 21 minutes**

No more leaves grew after the 12 minute mark. For minutes 15, 18, and 21, the yellow bulb at the top grew in size. After 21 minutes the plant was fully grown.

**[Here's a screenshot gallery showing the plant growth.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8RLy.jpg)** (*minor spoilers for post-game outfit*)

Comment: You can make the plants in the seaside kingdom grow faster by watering them with a captured squid.

Comment: @raznagul Will the Seaside Kingdom plants grow at the normal rate if they aren't watered?

Comment: Also of note, there is a plant in the Wooded Kingdom which will NOT grow based on time at all, though it is also different in that you don't have to put its seed into soil.

Comment: @zarose Yes, the Seaside plants  will grow without being watered. (I didn’t know you could water them when I tested)

Comment: @zarose yes, but one of them is massive so you'll be waiting a long time